# Mysql how to select row where field's array contains this value

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table structure "posts"

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | post  | authors_ids   |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 1  | test1 | ["1","2"]     |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 2  | test2 | ["1","3"]     |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 3  | test3 | ["3","4","5"] |
+----+-------+---------------+
```

what i want to do is to select rows that contains in `authors_ids` field a particular value for example i need to select the posts where authors_ids array  contains number `4`

i know that the table structure is wrong but at this time i will not be able to change it.

how can i achieve that ?

Comment: for mysql < 5.7 `select * from posts where authors_ids like '%"4"%'`

Comment: Assuming that's JSON in there, then: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: Consider normalising your schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick way to achieve this would be to select using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `authors_ids` LIKE '%"4"%';
```

Comment: what if the `authors_ids` has this value`["3","4","5","44","441","442","334"]`

Comment: It will still work because it includes the double quotes in the select. So `"44"` or `"441"` would not match